# Insert date only (not time) in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to insert a document with the current date.

What I've done so far is in here:

*query*

```js
const collectionSchema = new Schema({
    date: new Date()
});

const data = mongoose.model('data', collectionSchema);
```

When I try to insert data into mongodb the data is getting inserted with `date & time GMT` format.

But what I want is, to insert the date (`dd/mm/yyyy`) only instead of Date and Time GMT (`Date Wed Nov 10 2021 12:15:30 GMT+0400`) format.

How can achieve it with a minimal code?

Comment: Do you want to insert the current Date by default if not defined upon insert or are you asking how update/insert a document with a specific date?

Comment: Yes, but date only not time .

Comment: @PradipDhakal check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to add only date with mongoose npm package , for reference you can check it with URL ,

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-dateonly

Another way is that you can use moment , Which you can use as ,

```
date.toDateString()
date.toUTCString()
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Welcome.. @PradipDhakal

Answer (score 0):

Change your schema to this:

```
const collectionSchema = new Schema({
     date: {
         type: Date,
         default: new Date()
     }
})
```

So, Whenever a new collection is created the date will be automatically entered.

Comment: No man . IT insert like this
` $date: 2017-11-30T14:41:12.337Z `
But I want like this:
    ` $date: 2017-11-30 `

Comment: Well, if you're saying that you probably do not know how Date works in javascript, you're using mlab's editor which shows $date and parses it. It actually inserts something like this: 1512066177433 and that you can use to get the date easily.

Comment: @PradipDhakal I use a great library known as moment.js, try it and if you like it please upvote! https://momentjs.com